# java recursion: The factorial in int will go wrong when n>12

Tags: java, recursion, factorial

```
import java.util.Scanner;



public class factorial {
    public static void main(String [] args){
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int x = 0, y;
        System.out.println("enter factorial number");
        if(in.hasNextInt()){
            x = in.nextInt();// check if the scanner's next token is an int
        }//end if
        y = factorial(x);
        System.out.println("factorials is "+y);
    }//end main

    private static int factorial(int n) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(n==0||n==1){
            return 1;
        }
        else 
        return n*factorial(n-1);//recursive call
    }//end factorial


}//end class
```

Comment: "go wrong" how?  You need to read about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  In particular, you need to tell us what the error is that you're getting, including input, expected output, actual output, full stack trace of any exceptions, etc.

Comment: Because 12! is just too big to fit in an integer.

Comment: A good rule of thumb is that the more effort you put into a question, the better the answers to it will be.

Comment: @Tunaki - 12! is 479,001,600. `Integer.MAX_VALUE` is 2,147,483,647, so there's plenty of room for 12!. It's 13! (6,227,020,800) that is too large. Right idea, though.

Comment: sorry. my question is when I input 12 as x, the result 13! is 1932053504. But 13! should be 6227020800. So what's wrong with this code?

Comment: @Ted Hopp thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 6):

This is because 13! is greater than the largest 32 bit integer.  In java int is always 32 bits.